# Nodejs - how group and export multiple functions in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, koa2

How can I group and export multiple functions in nodejs?

I am trying to group all my util functions in utils.js:

```
async function example1 () {
    return 'example 1'
}

async function example2 () {
    return 'example 2'
}

module.exports = { example1, example2 }
```

And then be imported in home.js:

```
  import { example1, example2 } from '../utils'

  router.get('/', async(ctx, next) => {
    console.log(example1()) // Promise { 'example 1' }

  })
```

I thought I would get `'example 1'` for the test case above?

Any ideas?

Comment: stupid question:  did you forget to call the function? like: `console.log(await example1());`?

Comment: You're getting `Promise { 'example 1' }` instead of `example 1` because you marked `example1` as async function (unclear) why. To get resolved value call it this way: `await example1()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would be my solution for your exporting problem! And don't mix `es5 exports` with `es6 imports`, that can get very weird - sometimes!

```
export const example1 = async () => {
   return 'example 1'
}

export const example2 = async () => {
   return 'example 2'
}


// other file
import { example1, example2 } from '../../example'
return example1()
```

Nevertheless if you have to mix them, just let me know! We can find a solution for this aswell!

---

**More about exporting modules and what can go wrong!**

[MDN Exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and the a short story about [the state of javascript modules](https://medium.com/webpack/the-state-of-javascript-modules-4636d1774358)

Comment: thanks for the answer.  how is `es5 exports` like? what is considered `es6 exports`

Comment: ES5 export is the old syntax like `module.defaults = { example1, example2 }`. The newer (ES6) one is `export default { example1, example2 }`

Comment: thanks. what about this `export { example1, example2 }`? is it es5 as well?

Comment: Everything you see in this MDN documentation is ES6 exports: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: is this still es5, e.g. `module.exports = router;`?

Comment: Yes this is the es5 export syntax. Here's also a nice article about exporting and weird things, that may happen: https://medium.com/webpack/the-state-of-javascript-modules-4636d1774358

Comment: btw, i will get an error for `export default { example1, example2 }` - `TypeError: (0 , _utils.example1) is not a function` 
`

Comment: If you use the `export default` method, you have to import it like this: `import variable from '../file'`, but if you use `export const example1 = () => {}` then you have do the import like this `import { example1 } from '../file'`.

Comment: FYI you can also use the exact code you have as `export async function example1(){}`. Converting to arrows is a separate choice.

Answer (score 7):

Below I have shared a way to declare the exporting `functions` in **2 different ways**. Hope it helps understand the different ways in which it could be solved.

```
"use strict";
// utils.js

const ex1 = function() {
  console.log('ex1');
};

function ex2(context) {
  console.log('ex2');
};

module.exports = { example1: ex1, example2: ex2 };
```

You could invoke them in another (external) JS file (ex: app.js) as follows:

```
// app.js
const utils = require('./utils');

utils.example1(); // logs 'ex1'
utils.example2(); // logs 'ex2'
```

Comment: should ```module.exports = { ex1, ex2 };``` work if I import
```const utils = require('./utils');

utils.ex1();
utils.ex2(); ```

Answer (score 2):

```
async function example1 () {
    return 'example 1'
}

async function example2 () {
    return 'example 2'
}

module.exports.example1 = example1;
module.exports.example2 = example2;
```

import in home.js like this:

```
const fun = require('./utils');
fun.example1();
```